# Can't figure out ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException error

Tags: java

Thanks in advance for your feedback. I can't make sense of an ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException error in the snippet of code below. Is it obvious to any of you?

```
public void run() {
   int x = 10;
   int y = 10;

    double[][] Lx = new double[x][y];
    double[][] Ly = new double[x][y];

    for (int i=0; i<Lx.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<Lx[0].length; i++) {
            Lx[j][i] = 2*j+i-1;
            Ly[j][i] = Math.sqrt(3)*(i-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks rgettman, tintinmj, and user3071968. I had no idea I could save so much head banging this quickly.

Answer (score 5):

Your `j` for loop is incorrect in incrementing `i`, not `j`.  Change

```
for (int j=0; j<Lx[0].length; i++) {
```

to

```
for (int j=0; j<Lx[0].length; j++) {
```

In addition, your array access indices are backwards.  Change

```
Lx[j][i]
```

to

```
Lx[i][j]
```

and likewise with `Ly`.  Otherwise you'll get a flipped 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

With addition to @rgettman's answer

As in here your `x` and `y` is same so you will not have any issue with `Lx[0].length`. But it is good to use `Lx[i].length`.

`Lx[0].length` will **always** give the length or number of columns present in the `0th` row. But `Lx[i].length` will give the length or number of columns present in the `ith` row.

So in case your x and y differs you will not again get ArrayIndexOutBoundException.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `j++` not `i++` in the nested for-loop.

It's better not to use `i` and `j` for the index because they look too similar.

`i` and `k` are much more distinct than `i` and `j`